# What is wrong with my PHP image validation?

Tags: php

I'm having trouble figuring out why it is that when an image size is too big, I get the error 'Invalid File Type' 'Uploaded file is not an image' instead of getting 'File is too big' (The image validation/upload script I didn't completely write myself- I found the code and made it work with for my needs). Everything else seems to work fine except for this. Also I get the following warning

> Warning:  getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\minnow\includes\create-post.php on line 75

Here is my code

```
<?php
require_once('../dbconnect.php');
include_once( INCLUDES_PATH .'functions.php');

$body = $_POST["body"];
$image = 'image';
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

if( empty($_FILES[$image]['name']) ){
$has_image = 0;
}else{
$has_image = 1;
}

$postEmpty = 0;
$imageError = 0;

if( empty($_FILES[$image]['name']) && empty($body) ){
$postEmpty = 1;
die();
}

// validate post

if( $postEmpty == 0 && !empty($body) ){

    $cleanBody = clean_input($body);

}

// validate image (if any)

if( $has_image == 1 ){

    //check if directory exist if not create it
    if (!file_exists(HOME_PATH ."users/user_".$user_id)) {
        mkdir(HOME_PATH ."users/user_".$user_id, 0777, true);
    }
    if (!file_exists(HOME_PATH ."users/user_".$user_id."/posts")) {
        mkdir(HOME_PATH ."users/user_".$user_id."/posts", 0777, true);
    }
    //Set file upload path
    $path = "../users/user_".$user_id."/posts/"; //with trailing slash
    //Set max file size in bytes
    $max_size = 2000000;
    //Set default file extension whitelist
    $whitelist_ext = array('jpeg','jpg','png','gif');
    //Set default file type whitelist
    $whitelist_type = array('image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png','image/gif');

    // Create an array to hold any output
    $errors = array();

    // Get filename
    $file_info = pathinfo($_FILES[$image]['name']);
    $name = $file_info['filename'];
    $ext = $file_info['extension'];

    //Check file has the right extension           
    if (!in_array($ext, $whitelist_ext)) {
        $errors[] = "Invalid file Extension";
    }

    //Check that the file is of the right type
    if (!in_array($_FILES[$image]["type"], $whitelist_type)) {
        $errors[] = "Invalid file Type";
    }

    //Check that the file is not too big
    if ($_FILES[$image]["size"] > $max_size) {
        $errors[] = "File is too big";
    }

    //If $check image is set as true
    if ( !getimagesize($_FILES[$image]['tmp_name']) ) {
        $errors[] = "Uploaded file is not a valid image";
    }

    //Create full filename including path
    if ($random_name) {
    // Generate random filename
        $tmp = str_replace(array('.',' '), array('',''), microtime());

    if (!$tmp || $tmp == '') {
        $errors[] = "File must have a name";
    }     
        $newname = $tmp.'.'.$ext;                                
    } else {
        $newname = $name.'.'.$ext;
    }

    //Check if file already exists on server
    if (file_exists($path.$newname)) {
        $errors[] = "A file with this name already exists";
    }

    if (count($errors)>0) {
    //The file has not correctly validated
        $imageError = 1;
    }

 // if no errors:

    // upload image (if any) and retrieve filename
    if( $imageError == 1 ){

        $ret_data = ['items' => $errors, 'responseCode' => 0];
        //content in $items must be in UTF-8
        echo json_encode($ret_data);
        die();

    }else{

        //Create full filename including path
        // Generate random filename
        $tmp = str_replace(array('.',' '), array('',''), microtime());

        if (!$tmp || $tmp == '') {
            $errors[] = "File must have a name";
        }     

        $newname = $tmp.'.'.$ext;                                

        //Check if file already exists on server
        if (file_exists($path.$newname)) {
            $errors[] = "A file with this name already exists";
        }

        if (count($errors)>0) {
        //The file has not correctly validated
            $imageError = 1;
            $ret_data = ['items' => $errors, 'responseCode' => 0];
            //content in $items must be in UTF-8
            echo json_encode($ret_data);
            die();

        } 
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image]['tmp_name'], $path.$newname)) {

            $uploadSuccesfull = 1;

        }else {

            $ret_data = ['items' => $errors, 'responseCode' => 0];
            //content in $items must be in UTF-8
            echo json_encode($ret_data);
            die();
        }

    }
}


// if no errors:

// save post (with filename if any); if it fails, delete image (if any)
if( $has_image == 1 ){

$query = "INSERT INTO posts
        (user_id, body, image, has_image, date)
        VALUES
        ('$user_id', '$body', '$newname', '$has_image', now())";

}else{

    $query = "INSERT INTO posts
        (user_id, body, has_image, date)
        VALUES
        ('$user_id', '$body', '$has_image', now())";

}

$result = $db->query($query);

// send response

//check to make sure the user was added
if( $db->affected_rows == 1 ){

    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $post_id = $db->insert_id;

    $query = "SELECT post_id, body, image, has_image
            FROM posts
            WHERE post_id = $post_id
            LIMIT 1";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    if($result->num_rows == 1){
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }

    $queryuser = "SELECT *
                FROM users
                WHERE user_id = $user_id
                LIMIT 1";
    $resultuser = $db->query($queryuser);
    if($resultuser->num_rows == 1){
        $rowuser = $resultuser->fetch_assoc();
    }


if(!empty($row['avatar'])){ $userpic = $row['avatar']; }else{ $userpic = HOME_URL . 'img/avatar.jpg'; }

    if($row['has_image'] == 1){

    $data = "<article class='post'><div class='post-head cf'><a class='userpic' href=''><img src='$userpic' alt='".$rowuser['username']."'></a><a href='' class='username'>".$rowuser['username']."</a></div><img src='users/user_".$rowuser['user_id']."/posts/".$row['image']."' alt=''><div class='post-body'><div class='post-options'><a class='likes' href=''>156 likes</a></div><p><a class='username' href=''>".$rowuser['username']."</a>".$row['body']."</p><hr /><div class='cf'><a class='like hide-text' href='javascript:;'>Like This Post</a><form action='' class='comment'><input type='text' placeholder='Add a comment'></form></div></div></article>";
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

 }else{ 

$data = "<article class='post no-img'><div class='post-head cf'><a class='userpic' href=''><img src='$userpic' alt='".$rowuser['username']."'></a><a href='' class='username'>".$rowuser['username']."</a></div><div class='post-body'><p><a class='username' href=''>".$rowuser['username']."</a>".$row['body']."</p><div class='post-options'><a class='likes' href=''>1 like</a></div><hr /><div class='cf'><a class='like hide-text' href='javascript:;'>Like This Post</a><form action='' class='comment'><input type='text' placeholder='Add a comment'></form></div></div></article>";
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

}
    }else{

        $errors[] = "Server Error!";

        $ret_data = ['items' => $errors, 'responseCode' => 0];
        //content in $items must be in UTF-8
        echo json_encode($ret_data);

    }

die();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the file was just not uploaded to the server.

Check `$_FILES[$image]['error']` to see what may have gone wrong.

Refer to the error messages [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

**Edit:** After these lines:

```
$body = $_POST["body"];
$image = 'image';
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Do this:

```
// check for error greater than zero
if($_FILES[$image]['error'] > 0) {
    // something went wrong with the upload, handle the error
    echo $_FILES[$image]['error']; exit; // as an example to find out what the error was
}
```

Then refer to http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php to find out the reason.

Comment: Yea like I said I checked the error and it says it is an 'invalid file type' and 'uploaded file is not an image's instead of saying 'file is too big'

Comment: Those errors are custom errors in your code, not the actual file error from php. I will expand my answer to explain better.

Comment: Ohhhhh I see, the max file size was bigger than the one set in php ini thanks!